# How can i add a new date column to an existing table in sas

Tags: sas

I want to go back 6mo from existing date and  tried tbis but gives me the additional column NewDate with no values.

```
DATA temp;
SET  Have -- existing table
NewDate: Intx('Month',Date, -6)
run;
```

Comment: FYI - I removed the SQL tag as you're using a data step so it's not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

1. Missing semicolon on SET statement
2. DATE() is a function, you require the parenthesis
3. You need to use equal signs for assignment operations, not colon.
4. You're missing the fourth parameter for the INTNX() function - the alignment. What do you want that to be? I set it to same but please [review the documentation](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lefunctionsref/p10v3sa3i4kfxfn1sovhi5xzxh8n.htm). Also note that the documentation has usage examples that you can follow, if you scroll to the bottom of the page.

Here's a [video tutorial](https://video.sas.com/detail/videos/sas-analytics-u/video/4573023399001/creating-a-new-column-in-sas?autoStart=true&page=1) on the general concepts about creating a new variable.

```
data class;
set sashelp.class;

New_Date = intnx('month', date(), 6, 's');
run;
```